# NAs introduced by coercionError in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r

I am running following code

`class(TrainSet$volume)` that gives me `[1] "numeric"`

Then I run

`model1 <- randomForest(TrainSet$volume ~ ., data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)`

it gave me

`Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`

What could be the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to know for sure without more information about your data, but as the error suggests you seem to have one of those values (NA/NaN/Inf) somewhere in your data frame. Perhaps `inf` as `NA` tends to throw a different error. We can recreate your error below:

```
library(randomForest)

#setting data
data(iris)

#making an infinite value
iris[1,1] <- Inf

#grab row
iris[is.infinite(iris$Sepal.Length),]

#output
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          Inf         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

#checking data type
is.numeric(iris$Sepal.Length) #TRUE

#reproducing error
iris.rf <- randomForest(iris$Sepal.Width ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE)

#output
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

As to where or why this is in your data is unclear (again, need to see the data to make this call). A common way `inf` is created is by a mistake in per-processing that introduces a confused calculation, like dividing be zero.

```
is.infinite(pi / 0)
#output
# [1] TRUE
```

Scanning for infinites or NA (with `is.infinite` or `is.na`) and reviewing any changes you made to your data seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Besides missing data or infinities as Peter_Evan suggested, another possibility is a character variable in *TrainSet*. Therefore, run the following four lines:

```
any(is.na(TrainSet))
any(apply(TrainSet, 2, is.infinite))
any(apply(TrainSet, 2, is.nan))
any(is.character(TrainSet))
```

If any return TRUE, you have your problem.